# How to implement singleton pattern in the following situation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const instance = Symbol('instance');

class Parent {
    number;

    constructor() {
        const Class = this.constructor;

        if (!Class[instance]) Class[instance] = this;
        return Class[instance];
    }

    set_number (number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    test () { }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    test () { }
}

const child = new Child();
const parent = new Parent();
const child2 = new Child2();

child.set_number(1);
child.test();

child2.set_number(2);
child2.test(); // child2.test is not a function

parent.set_number(3);

console.log(child.number); // output : 1
console.log(child2.number); // output : 3 (I want it to be 2.)
console.log(parent.number); // output : 3
```

I implmented Singleton by assigning instances to the constructor.

I want to be implemented in singleton for each of the three classes *Parent*, *Child*, and *Child2*. But there is a problem, when I instantiate *Parent* class before other classes.

I tried to come up with good idea, but fail. Is there any way I can solve it?

[test URL](https://repl.it/repls/LimePointlessSoftwareagent)

Comment: singleton class means only one instance (which means only one memory location for number), and that's y (child.number == child2.number) will be `true` always, you have to declare `number` as class variable of child to get your required output

Comment: @Vivek Thank you :) Um... (I'm not accustomed to English, I'm hard to explain it in plain English.) I want to implmenet three singleton pattern to each of the classes. For example, if I instantiate *Parent* class many times, *parent.number*, *parent2.number* and *parent3.number* will be exactly the same, but I don't wanted that to be the same as *child.number* or *child2.number*. So I chose the way assigning instacnces to the constrctor.

Comment: @Vivek I didn't understand to declare *number* as class variable of child.. You mean declare a *number* variable to *Child* and *Child2* like a top line in *Parent*? (I knew that variable has no initiation, so any code is converted by babel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class[instance]` looks up `instance` throughout the prototype (inheritance) chain.  So in case of `Child2` it starts with `Child2`, and if there is no property it continues with `Parent`, then with `Object`. The result is that you return an instance of `Parent` when you want create the instance of `Child2`.

Instead of checking the existence of the property by using a lookup, you should use `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
if (!Class.hasOwnProperty(instance)) Class[instance] = this;
```

That means if `Child2` itself(!) does not have an instance, then assign one to it.

Comment: Yes! that's rihgt. Thank you so much. I just read over a converted source code, and I found *subClass.__proto__ = superClass;*. I thought whether check class name at if statement. But your way of hasOwnProperty() is good. Everything is comfortable. :D